# Log4j - with hibernate 4.02

Tags: hibernate, log4j

For our application I was asked to log the sql queries only in debug mode. We are using hibernate core 4.02. Here below I included log4j properties.
As you see the root level is INFO but still it logs sql statements to the logs. But my requirement is to log it only when the root level is debug. Can you please suggest what is that I am doing wrong?

```
# log4j properties

#*************************************************************************
#*************************************************************************

#-------------------Appender options--------------------------------------
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, destFile
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, destFile

#-------------------Console options---------------------------------------
log4j.appender.destConsole=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.destConsole.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.destConsole.layout.ConversionPattern=%x %m%n

#-------------------File options------------------------------------------
log4j.appender.destFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.destFile.File=../logs/LQA_GUI.log
log4j.appender.destFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.destFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMMdd HH:mm:ss:SSS} %x %m%n
log4j.appender.destFile.MaxFileSize=4096KB
log4j.appender.destFile.MaxBackupIndex=300

# -------------------Log Hibernate------------------------------------------
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.stat=DEBUG
```

Comment: What are you trying to tell? you want all the logs to be running only if the root level of log is **INFO**?

Comment: I want the SQl query to be logged only when the log4j.rootLogger is in Debug. As you see currently I have log level as INFO but still I see SQl queries been logged

Comment: the issue got resolved when i added org.hibernate.SQL to the rootLogger like this log4j.rootLogger.org.hibernate.SQL. Can someone suggest is it a good approach